# Replace multiple placeholders in string

Tags: ios

What I am looking to do is use placeholders in a string and replace the placeholders with data specific to the user. I can setup the placeholders to be anything so basically I am looking to do the following:

1. Setup placeholders in a string (up to 4 placeholders)
2. Replace those placeholders with strings I specify

Here is what I have. I currently have a url that has a set of placeholders like so. http://example.com/resource?placeholder1=placeholder2  or  http://placeholder1:placeholder2@example.com/something?placeholder3

How do I properly label the placeholders and replace them?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Links are not working.

Comment: they are not real links. They are examples of what I am working with. If you look at the links above they contain the words placeholder1 placeholder2 etc. I am looking to replace those placeholders with strings I specify which will be generated based on the logged in user.

Comment: For example I want to replace placeholder1 with an NSString I have already created called value1 and placeholder2 with an NSString called key1.

Comment: What is your real issue? Getting the text from the label? `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`? `stringWithFormat:`?

Comment: My issue is how do I replace the placeholders in the url examples above with text from Strings.    http://example.com/resource?placeholder1=placeholder2    is stored as a string. I need to replace those placeholders (placeholder1 and placeholder2) with strings I feed them. I am not sure how to do this with multiple placeholders in place and if the placeholders have to be in any specific format or if they can be named placeholder1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** method as below

```
NSString *strUrl = @"http://example.com/resource?placeholder1=placeholder2";
strUrl = [strUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"placeholder1" withString:@"value1"];
strUrl = [strUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"placeholder2" withString:@"key1"];
```

Comment: This should work. I will need to test but this looks to be exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quote :  *"I want to replace placeholder1 with an NSString I have already created called value1 and placeholder2 with an NSString called key1."*

```
NSString *mainUrl = "http://example.com/resource";
NSString *string1 = "value1";
NSString *string2 = "value2";

Now change your URL:

NSString *newURL = [NSString NSStringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@",mainUrl,string1,string2];
```

This will generate `newURL` : `http://example.com/resource?value1=value2`

Comment: Ok that will work fine for that example. The problem I have is going to be with the other example. I am grabbing this url with placeholders from a database. Each user could potentially have access to several urls. It would be much easier for this example http://placeholder1:placeholder2@example.com/something?placeholder3 if the placeholders could just be swapped with strings. If I need to change the name placeholder with something else that would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
#define placeHolder1 @"<>p1p1p1<>"
#define placeHolder2 @"<>p2p2p2<>"
```

And place this in a function of yours where you want to replace strings

```
    NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/resource?%@=%@",placeHolder1,placeHolder2];

    NSLog(@"string  %@",string);

    NSString * replacerForP1 = @"123";
    NSString * replacerForP2 = @"741";

    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:placeHolder1
                                      withString:replacerForP1];

    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:placeHolder2
                                      withString:replacerForP2];

    NSLog(@"string  %@",string);
```

It would be best to keep your placeholder strings in the constants defined somewhere. And ofcourse the replacement of those placeholders will be dynamic as you said so cannot make them constants.

Tell me if this helps or if you require further assistance in the matter.